# How to execute shell command and echo multiple lines from PHP?

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

Re,

I use a shell command `cat` to dump multiple lines into a file like so:

```
cat > file <<CHAR
one
two
three
CHAR
```

Here's my problem: I need to execute the same `cat` command using `shell_exec` in PHP. How would I dump the contents of an array and terminate the command with `CHAR`? I know this sounds odd but I need to create a file using `sudo` and I don't want to dump everything into a temporary file and then `sudo cp` it to the intended location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
shell_exec('cat > file <<EOF
foo
bar
EOF
');
```

Of course this will only work if the underlying shell supports the here-doc syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I had to implode my array using `PHP_EOL` to make it work.

Comment: Your join with `\n` won't work as it will produce a single-line file with line breaks not being recognized. That's why I used `PHP_EOL`

Comment: I've tested this code. you need double quotes if you need escape sequences: `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`popen()`](http://php.net/popen) instead of `shell_exec()`:

```
$filename = 'file';
$text = 'CHAR
one
two
three
';

$cmdline = 'cat > ' . escapeshellarg($filename);
$fp = popen('sudo /bin/sh -c ' . escapeshellarg($cmdline), 'w');
fwrite($fp, $text);
pclose($fp);
```

Comment: `popen` is an interesting alternative. thanks, I will read up on it!